# how to prevent redux generate sub object of same property after dispatch an action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

the code below works fine, except something weird, 
initial props is an empty object `{ photos: {} }`

after invoking action creator the state in component looks like

```
{ photos: photos : {...} }
```

whereas I expect only `photos: {...}`
[image]

What cause this and how can I prevent generate another sub property in state?

component:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getPhotos} from '../actions'
class Photos extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount(){
       this.props.getPhotos();
    }
    invokeFunc= () =>{
        this.props.getPhotos();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PhotoItem />
                <button onClick={()=> this.invokeFunc()} >call action creator</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {photos} = state;
    return {
        photos,
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getPhotos})(Photos)
```

action creator:

```
export const getPhotos =  () =>{
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const response = await PhotosApi.get('/photos')
        dispatch({
            type:"GET_PHOTOS",
            payload:response
        }) 
    }
}
```

reducer.js

```
const photosReducer = (state = {}, action) =>{
    if(action.type=="GET_PHOTOS"){
        return {...state, photos:action.payload}
      }
      return state;
}

export default combineReducers({
    photos:photosReducer,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer is returning an object with `photos` as a property in it. Instead, try returning an object that *is* the photos property.

```
const photosReducer = (state = {}, action) =>{
  switch(action.type){
    case "GET_PHOTOS":
      return { ...state, action.payload }; // or just `{ action.payload }` if you want it to wipe out the last state

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  photos:photosReducer,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is `combineReducers`. From docs

> The combineReducers helper function turns an object whose values are different reducing functions into a single reducing function you can pass to createStore.
>
> The resulting reducer calls every child reducer, and gathers their results into a single state object. The state produced by combineReducers() namespaces the states of each reducer under their keys as passed to combineReducers()

So, since you are giving the namespace `photos` to your reducer, `photosReducer` state is under key `photos` in your global state.